# How can I pass an object in a function as an argument in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, mongodb

Given two objects which extend a class:

```
object PageDAO
  extends SalatDAO[Page, Long](collection=Config.getMongoDB("db_development")("pages"))

object BookDAO
  extends SalatDAO[Book, Long](collection=Config.getMongoDB("db_development")("books"))
```

I want to write a function which has the object as a parameter:

```
def find[ID](salatDAO:SalatDAO[Product,ID]) = salatDAO.find(MongoDBObject()).limit(10)
```

Like

```
scala> find[Long](PageDAO)
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : PageDAO.type (with underlying type object PageDAO)
 required: com.novus.salat.dao.SalatDAO[Product,Long]
Note: Page <: Product (and PageDAO.type <: com.novus.salat.dao.SalatDAO[Page,Long]), but class SalatDAO is invariant in type ObjectType.
You may wish to define ObjectType as +ObjectType instead. (SLS 4.5)
       find[Long](PageDAO)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried the tip of the compiler?

Comment: I don't understand what the compiler tip actually means. Where do I attach the +ObjectType onto? as a part of the SalatDAO definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the advice of the compiler. If you want `SalatDAO[A, _]` to be a subclass of `SalatDAO[B, _]` when `A <: B` (i.e., when `A` is a subclass of `B`), declare `SalatDAO` to be *covariant* in its first parameter:

```
trait SalatDAO[+A, B] // ...
               ^       <-- that plus does the trick
```

If you cannot change the variance annotation, you can use usage-site bounds, à la Java, as Eastsun proposed in the comments:

```
def find[P <: Product, I](salatDAO: SalatDAO[P,I]) = // ...
```

Comment: What if i cannot alter the SalatDAO trait? It is a librayr and not a part of my codebase. https://github.com/novus/salat/blob/master/salat-core/src/main/scala/com/novus/salat/dao/SalatDAO.scala